# How to Set List of System Properties On COmmand Line

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-config

I want to set a system properties which is a list of values on the command line. For example,

```scala
sbt run -Dfoo=   <- my list
```

If I was to put this in an application.conf I would do this:

foo = ["abc", "bcd"]

How would I do this on the command line? I know how to do it from one string value but I need to pass list.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (and that this is the easiest way points out a problem with Lightbend Config to the point that lists in config is something I try to avoid!) is to pass each value as a distinct property:

`-Dfoo.0=abc -Dfoo.1=bcd`

That's really clunky, needless to say.  When I control the config, I prefer to encode arbitrary-length lists of strings as comma-separated string and break it apart in the application.  When there's a limited arity, I'll synthesize the list in config as a list of other properties.  Both approaches facilitate configuration by environment variable (especially useful in containers).

Comment: I have no control over this config. It is required by another Play library I depend on otherwise I agree that list is not good in config.